# Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'Properties<ReactText, string & {}>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function react element which looks like this

```
import { CSSProperties } from 'styled-components'
export interface StylesDictionary {
  [Key: string]: CSSProperties
}
interface Props {
  onClick: () => void
  buttonStyle?: StylesDictionary
}
export default function PreviewButton({ onClick, buttonStyle }: Props) {
```

When I am trying to pass it a style like this

```
   <PreviewButton
      buttonStyle={{ marginLeft: '20px' }}
      onClick={() => onClickPreview(api, tableDefinition)}
    />
```

Typescript is giving following error

```
Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'Properties<ReactText, string & {}>'
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

That is because your type definition of `StylesDictionary` is not done right: If you define `StylesDictionary` the way you are right now:

```
export interface StylesDictionary {
  [Key: string]: CSSProperties
}
```

Then on your `PreviewButton` props, `buttonStyle` should be:

```
<PreviewButton
  buttonStyle={{ anyValue: {marginLeft: '20px'} }}
  onClick={() => onClickPreview(api, tableDefinition)}
/>
```

Where `anyValue` can be anything, as long as it is a string
This will show no errors, but I'm sure this is not how you want it to be

To make it work how I guess you intend it, you simply remove `StylesDictionary`, and change `interface Props` to be:

```
interface Props {
  onClick: () => void
  buttonStyle?: CSSProperties
}
```

Then you will be able to wright `buttonStyle` as you intend it to:

```
<PreviewButton
  buttonStyle={{ marginLeft: '20px' }}
  onClick={() => onClickPreview(api, tableDefinition)}
/>
```